# JavaFX ListView - remove spacing / padding / margin between cells

Tags: java, css, listview, javafx, javafx-2

As I have **custom cells** for a particular `ListView`, I have big trouble to understand how to to remove the "natural" sort of margin / spacing there is between each cells, and, even worse, on the right and left sides of said cells.

Here's an example:

[image: image to showcase spacing between cells]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NoWBk.png)

As you can see, I use a color to bring out each cell. You cannot see the space at the end of the cells (on their right side), because I need to scroll, but you can trust me, the white space is equal on each side (bigger on the left & right, though...) which is not normal as I have specifically designed these cells so that their width is as large as the `ListView` so that there is no need to use horizontal scrolling. My issue kinds of defeat my purpouse...

Each cell consists of one **AnchorPane** with the image and the one label.
The `AnchorPane` is painted in yellow (`-fx-background-color: yellow;`).

And as you can clearly see, there is these white spaces all around the cells.

FYI, here I am using **JavaFX 8 / 2.2 SDK** but I intend to use [JFoenix](https://github.com/jfoenixadmin/JFoenix) `JFXListView` & `JFXListCell`. However, the spacing is even worse using those.

Strange point: I also painted the `ListView`in green, but such color is nowhere. to be seen. I guess all the cells (and the empty one) overwrites the `ListView` content, so it would make sense not to see its background. However, this means the cells are somehow "corrupted" since white spaces are "added" all around my cells.

I have tried to set padding to 0 for everything but in vain.

Finally, in the `onUpdateItem` method, I do call the **super method** and when the cell is not flagged as **empty**, I set the graphic to the aforementioned AnchorPane otherwise I set it to null, which is clearly consistent to my screenshot.

Thanks for the help !

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you look at the default CSS stylesheet for JavaFX, [modena.css](https://github.com/javafxports/openjdk-jfx/blob/0825768cc8421edf3a3d63a073f9e78e4961e1b0/modules/javafx.controls/src/main/resources/com/sun/javafx/scene/control/skin/modena/modena.css#L2320), you'll see:

```css
.list-cell {
    -fx-padding: 0.25em 0.583em 0.25em 0.583em; /* 3 7 3 7 */
}
```

This is where the padding for the `ListCell`s is coming from. To remove this padding simply add your own stylesheet which contains:

```css
.list-cell {
    -fx-padding: 0px;
}
```

Or call `setStyle` for each of your `ListCell`s:

```
setStyle("-fx-padding: 0px;");
```

The second option would best be done by using a custom [cell factory](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/javafx/scene/control/ListView.html#cellFactoryProperty).

```
listView.setCellFactory(v -> new ListCell<>() {

    {
        setStyle("-fx-padding: 0px");
    }

    @Override
    protected void updateItem(Object item, boolean empty) {
        super.updateItem(item, empty);
        if (empty || item == null) {
            setText(null);
            setGraphic(null);
        } else {
            // your custom display logic
        }
    }

});
```

Also, after some quick testing with JFoenix it looks like using the above will also work for `JFXListCell`; though you have to be careful about overriding `updateItem` because `JFXListCell` does *a lot* in its implementation.

Comment: I wanna know what is the Skins story of JavaFx I know it's not related to the question

Comment: You Sir have my thanks.
I haved added the `setStyle("-fx-padding: 0px;");` in the constructor of my custom `ListCell` and using normal `ListView` it did the trick. Next: `JFXListView` and `JFXListCell`. It did not work. Because as you said, `onUpdateitem` does quite a lot.. Among that, a clear bug where `setText(item.toString())` is called if item is not a `Node`. Which displays the instance and class name right after my `graphic`. Plus it overrides the style as well. So I have to call `setStyle("-fx-padding: 0px;");` after super method as well as `setText(null)`. I'll mark your answer ;-)

Comment: @AhmedEmad read a basic tutorial - see f.i.  the info tab of the javafx tag :)

Comment: I have been working with javafx for a while now it's just I'm not a big fan of CSS although I can make my custom CSS files and assign them to whatever component I want but then I wanna to select a certain class like (the scroll bar arrow and thumb) I kept searching every where till I found something and not in the documentation

Comment: @AhmedEmad Have you seen the [JavaFX CSS Reference Guide](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html)? It gives decent documentation about how to style the standard layouts/controls/charts. This includes styling the scroll bar's components.

Comment: I have seen it before it's a little bit ugly designed and I don't get how to use some selectors like for example if we are talking about the scroll bar component I can't say how to select the thumb or what options are there for me

Answer (score -1):

I set the red background of the cell as default to make sure that the artifacts I see between cells are in fact created by the `.list-cell`.

No matter how hard I tried, I could not get rid of it, even with the padding `0px`. The red background was still visible every other cell in my case.

I suppose, it is a rounding error...

So, the only thing that worked was using a negative padding to remove any spacing | padding | margin between cells.

```css
.list-cell{
    -fx-font-weight: normal;
    -fx-text-fill: white;
    -fx-padding: -1px;
    -fx-background-color: red;
}
```